# How do I make an exponential function that doubles every fifth integer.

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I don't understand exponential functions too well, so if you know the answer, please also show me the process I would use to come up with it.

I'm trying to figure out how to make an exponential function that doubles every five whole integers. That would mean that:

```
|input|output|
|:---:|:----:|
|f(1) |1     |
|f(6) |2     |
|f(11)|4     |
|f(16)|8     |
```

et cetera.

I know some people have suggested using a best-fit application, but I don't think those things are too accurate. Is there a tried and true process to creating a function that matches these outputs?

Comment: How about $2^{(x-1)/5}=\left(\sqrt[5]2\right)^{x-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an exponential function. This means it is of the form
$$
f(n)=a\cdot b^n
$$
for some numbers $a,b$. You also want $f(1)=1,f(6)=2$. That's enough to solve your problem:
$$
\cases{a\cdot b^1=1\\
a\cdot b^6=2}
$$
Dividing equation two by equation one, we get $b^5=2$. This is exactly the equation fifth roots are made to solve: $b=\sqrt[5]2$. Inserting this into equation one, we get $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{2}}$. Thus our function must be
$$
f(n)=\frac{\sqrt[5]2^n}{\sqrt[5]2}
$$

Comment: So If I'm understanding correctly, to figure out the function, I would need to take two different outputs in ab^x form, and divide them by each other? Is that what you did there?

Comment: @moonbeast32 Taking two different outputs in that form is what you must do. Dividing them by one another seemed like the fastest way to get at a solution, but I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: ok, thanks @Arthur that helps a lot.